# Is making simple website in "java spring hibernate" is overkilling

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

Initially i was php programmer and was using joomla to build websites .
I could easily build good websites in joomla in few days.

I was learning java spring hibernate  for last three months and now i have build simple user registration logins and members area using spring MVC , hibernate annotation etc.

Now i want to ask that whether from now onwards should i use spring MVC to build site just because i have learned it or its good for me in future.  Because i still feel that the same site can be build in few days in php

Is it the case that in future i can also come on same level as php that i can build simple site in java in few days as well or no matter what experience i have java still is going to take longer than php always

Can any java CMS make my life easier because i want to say good bye to php.
i mean if i want to make just 5 page portfolio website can build in java cms in 1-2 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "simple website" you mean a normal page with categories, articles and some navigation (i.e. not a web-application), then yes: Building that from the grounds up with Java + Spring + Hibernate is probably overkill (i.e. those are low-level tools, you'd have to build a lot yourself). I'd stick with the tools built for this specific task, namely some kind of CMS system.

If you want to bring "some Java" into your day-to-day job, then you might want to try looking into a [Java CMS system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419968/best-open-source-java-cms).

Answer (score 0):

You should, of course, use the appropriate tools for the job. Spring MVC is not appropriate if you are re-implementing functionality that has already been robustly provided by an existing tool (eg. Joomla etc.).

Given that much of the 'interactive' part of many websites can now be hosted elsewhere (eg. Disqus for comments and so on), you may not need a dynamic website at all and could host the site on one of the many cloud services for static content. This has the advantage that your performance is elastic, and 'cost per user' can be vanishingly low.